# Create TABLE using PHP, according to input

Tags: php

I am about to create a table, but I want to declare it based on the user's input. thankyou for any response, all answers are appreciated, more power!

I am receiving this error (Error creating table: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''2020-2021' ( id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, firstname VARCHAR' at line 1)

here's the sample code I am doing.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "mias";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$table = $_POST['usersinput'];

// sql to create table
$sql = "CREATE TABLE $table (
id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
firstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
lastname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
email VARCHAR(50),
reg_date TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
)";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Table MyGuests created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error creating table: " . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: This can be extremely dangerous as it is wide open to SQL injection.  Using user input to a SQL statement is not recommended - especially as you cannot even use a prepared statement due to the table name being the input.

Comment: Also do you really need to create a new table?  Would you be better off using 1 database table with some form of identifier to associate the data with a particular user/set of data?

Comment: So, did you mean? I must ready my tables until it's time to use?

Comment: Yeah, I also tried to think of that, I am creating an enrollment system, and go for the basis of the school year for filtering them, but is it too much data just for one table?

Comment: My plan is to programmatically create a table every school year. to insert students in every table in every school year

Comment: How many rows are you expecting?   It should cater for at least 16TB of data.

Comment: I expect more than that, try to imagine students are enrolling every year, so let's expect that 16tb is lack

Comment: you cannot use `-` in a table name. An underscore would be acceptable though

Comment: I tried putting manually in PHPMyAdmin the 2020-2021 table, it was inserted.

Comment: considering that the table name was intended to be years ( from-to ) you can certainly construct a much better table schema to suit your needs

Comment: but programmatically, it can't accept (-), thankyou :)

Comment: You really think you are going to need more than 16tb of data for a list of pupils?  That should include most of the population of the world.

Comment: Anyway - just try putting backticks round the table name `CREATE TABLE \`$table\`(`

Comment: hehe, THANKYOU so much for the answers, Super Appreciated, also to sir Nigel Ren :)

Comment: I think in a years time you might look back and think - `"hmm, I wish I had created a different schema"` - afterall each pupil just needs the year of enrollment against their name

Comment: backticks are effective, thankyou sir Nigel Ren, I also tried thinking other schemas, such as putting the pupils inside one table, and filter them in 1 table, but I have encountered a problem on that situation, so I will try this method if it's really effective

Answer (score 0):

Try this code by replacing your code. It will work. i have tried. Problem in your last line of your code.

```
CREATE TABLE $table(
id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
firstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
lastname VARCHAR(30),
email VARCHAR(50),
reg_date TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

Answer (score 0):

As Nigel has said in the comment, it's definitely a bad idea to allow user input to create a table.

How I would think about doing this would be to use relationships between the `Table Guests` and the `Table` or `Booking` you want them to be added to.

You would just need to create two tables, one for the `Booking` and one for the `Guests` then in the `Guests` table, have a `Booking_ID` field which would contain the `ID` of the bookings the user should be added to.

This way, when you want to look for Guests for a specific table, you would be able to do `SELECT * FROM MyGuests WHERE booking_id=[the booking id]` and this would return the guests for that table.

Comment: Thank you sir, Appreciated :) creating the table is not for the user, it was for the Admin.

Answer (score 0):

Like other users stated there are several reasons (most importantly security) not to do that, but if you really want it you have to use concatenation for your string:

1. Option

   `$sql = "CREATE TABLE {$table}(id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, firstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, lastname VARCHAR(30), email VARCHAR(50), reg_date TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)";`
2. Option

   `$sql = "CREATE TABLE" . $table . "(id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, firstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, lastname VARCHAR(30), email VARCHAR(50), reg_date TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)";`